# CSS & Bootstrap Custom Burn Transition

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, transition, backbone-layout-manager

Hey guys i am trying to create a quick burn effect. I am using Backbonejs, Backbone Layout manager and twitter bootstrap. I have a wrapper div which contains a bunch of tex fields, imgs, labels, ect... the wrapper div is controlled by a backbone layout view. Contained in the wrapper div is a button that allows you to restore all fields to their default value. The effect i had in mind is similar to holding a piece of paper vertically in the air and lighting it on fire at the bottom. Currently when the restore button is clicked i just re-render the view with default values. so instead when the restore button is click i would like div to appear to burn up and after the entire div has been burned the div re-renders itself with the new values.

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-8">
                    <img src="img/defaultContact.png" class="img-thumbnail" style="max-height: 150px;">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" id="contact-detail-save-button">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> Save
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" id="contact-detail-restore-button">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> Restore
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">First Name</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Contacts First Name" value="{{firstname}}" id="details-firstname">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Last Name</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Contacts Last Name" value="{{lastname}}" id="details-lastname">
            </div>
            ...</div>
```

I have no code so far. I am new to client side development and am not sure where to start.

A possible way to do this is to have a image of fire and scale it over the screen. is there a way to have scalable images?

Comment: Code would be nice. What have you tried so far?